# How can i insert the document type(name) and its respective image in database with every file upload in codeigniter

Tags: php, mysql, codeigniter

What exactly i need to do is: User can select the Document Type (like, passport, driving licence, voter Id etc.) from the drop down and the its respective image he wants to upload. Suppose he is to upload 4 documents then he should be able to select the document type for each upload from the drop-down next to the "file" input type :

This is the code i tried so far, but it is inserting Nothing in the table, though it is working fine with one drop-down and multiple file upload

In my controller:

```
    $this->customer_model->upload_doc();        
    redirect('/customer/index', 'location', 301);
```

In Model:

```
    public function upload_doc()
{
    if(isset($_FILES['userfile']))
    {
        $name_array = array();
        $count = count($_FILES['userfile']['size']);
        foreach($_FILES as $key=>$value)
        for($s=0; $s<=$count-1; $s++) 
        {
            $_FILES['userfile']['name'] = $value['name'][$s];
            $_FILES['userfile']['type'] = $value['type'][$s];
            $_FILES['userfile']['tmp_name'] = $value['tmp_name'][$s];
            $_FILES['userfile']['error'] = $value['error'][$s];
            $_FILES['userfile']['size'] = $value['size'][$s];   
            $config['upload_path'] = './assets/document/';
            $config['allowed_types'] = 'gif|jpg|png';
            $config['max_size'] = '';
            $config['max_width'] = '';
            $config['max_height'] = '';
            $this->load->library('upload', $config);
            $this->upload->do_upload();
            $data = $this->upload->data();

            $name_array[] = $data['file_name'];
        }           
            //$names= implode(',', $name_array);

            foreach($name_array as $name)
            {
                $db_data = array(
                        'documentType' => $this->input->post('idproof'),
                        'image' => $name,

                );          
                $this->db->insert('document',$db_data);
            }
    //print_r($db_data);
        //die();
    //die();
        //print_r($names);
    }
}
```

In View:

```
 Id Proof<?php echo form_dropdown('idProof1', $document,'', 'class= "form-control"');  ?><input type="file" name="userfile[]" id="userfile" size="20" />
<?php echo form_dropdown('idProof2', $document,'', 'class= "form-control"');  ?>    <input type="file" name="userfile[]" id="userfile" size="20" />
<?php echo form_dropdown('idProof3', $document,'', 'class= "form-control"');  ?>    <input type="file" name="userfile[]" id="userfile" size="20" />

 <button class="btn btn-white" type="submit">Cancel</button>
 <button class="btn btn-primary" type="submit">Save changes</button>
```

Please guide me where i am doing wrong, if anyone have idea.
Thank You

Comment: why you have used `$this->db->insert_id();` after upload

Comment: @Vinie because i need to insert the customer id for which the documents are uploaded, i fetched that customer id through this

Comment: First, i cannot understand from where are you taking the ID, can you please share the lines before  $id = $this->db->insert_id();, also in your view, open a multipart form to send the file contents to controller

Comment: @Dario i have edited the code above, $this->db->insert_id(); i delete this line coz its causing confusion. I already open a multipart form like this: <?php echo form_open_multipart('customer/add') ?>

Comment: print_r($name_array) and use $this->db->last_query()  to see what value is in array and your last query.

Comment: @Vinie in the print_r($name_array) i am getting the array of images i choose to upload but i am not getting any documentType, its is showing this " INSERT INTO `document` (`documentType`, `image`, `customerId`) VALUES (0, '631325.png', 91) " in $this->db->last_query(). I guess there is some problem in my dropdowns name....but dont know what

Comment: print_r your $_POST data and check your dropdown is posting any data or not

Comment: @Vinie it is showing nothing a blank page. I did this     print_r ($this->input->post('idproof'));
    die();

Comment: @Vinie it is showing an Array now post values of all document type Array ( [0] => 2 [1] => 1 [2] => 1 [3] => 1 ) and showing n error of  Array to string conversion

Comment: then why so it is in array form? Is it multiple select? If yes the please implode $this->input->post('idproof') or do whatever as your need.

Answer (score 0):

I have done it with the help of below code:

in view i did made the name attribute as array `<?php echo form_dropdown('idProof[]', $document,'', 'class= "form-control"');  ?>`

in model i modified the function something like this:

```
    public function upload_doc()
{
    if(isset($_FILES['userfile']))
    {
        $name_array = array();
        $count = count($_FILES['userfile']['size']);
        $time=time();
        $id = $this->db->insert_id();
        $doc=$this->input->post('idProof');
        $j = 0;
        foreach($_FILES as $key=>$value)
        for($s=0; $s<=$count-1; $s++) 
        {
            $_FILES['userfile']['name'] = $id."_".$doc[$j]."_".$time."_".$value['name'][$s];
            $_FILES['userfile']['type'] = $value['type'][$s];
            $_FILES['userfile']['tmp_name'] = $value['tmp_name'][$s];
            $_FILES['userfile']['error'] = $value['error'][$s];
            $_FILES['userfile']['size'] = $value['size'][$s];   
            $config['upload_path'] = './userData/';
            $config['allowed_types'] = 'gif|jpg|png|doc|docx|pdf';
            $config['max_size'] = '';
            $config['max_width'] = '';
            $config['max_height'] = '';
            $this->load->library('upload', $config);
            $this->upload->do_upload();
            $data = $this->upload->data();

            $name_array[] = $data['file_name'];
            $j++;
        }           
            //$names= implode(',', $name_array);


            //$doc=$this->input->post('idProof');
            //die();
            $documentType[] = $this->input->post('idProof');
            $keyIndex=0;
            foreach($name_array as $name)
            {


                $db_data = array(
                        'documentType' => $doc[$keyIndex],
                        'image' => $name,
                        'customerId' => $id
                );          
                $this->db->insert('document',$db_data);
                $keyIndex++;
            }
    //print_r($db_data);
        //die();
    //die();
        //print_r($names);
    }
```

Thank you for the suggestions guys i made it work from it..